# Retornar registros campo Timestamp()

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `interessados`, nela tenho `int_data` este campo é `timestamp()`, tenho 5 registros com as seguintes datas:

```
2016-09-01 10:15:00
2016-09-01 10:50:00
2016-09-01 18:35:00
2016-09-01 23:15:00
2016-09-15 10:00:00
```

Como eu faço para selecionar apenas os do dia `01/09/2016`? Sendo que é `timestamp()` e eu não consigo fazer `WHERE int_data`?

Comment: Faça o teste `SELECT to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 
  numtodsinterval(1472760605, 'SECOND') as TIMESTAMP
FROM DUAL` e vem resultado `01/09/2016 20:10:05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faço isso no firebird:

```
select * from interessados where cast(int_data as date) = '01/09/2016'
```

faço um cast no campo e trabalho como um date simples

Answer (score 1):

consegue sim bastz fazer da seguinte forma

```
WHERE date(int_data) ='20160901'
```

ou ainda de forma mais "relaxada"

```
 WHERE int_data like '2016-09-01%'
```

na primeira solução vc faz o mysql processar a data e na segunda vc apenas filtra como c fosse uma `String`